# Exporting Data into a CSV - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, csv, excel

Say I have a function that generates some data into cells into the current worksheet like :

```
Cells(1, "A").Value = ...
Cells(2, "A").Value = ...
Cells(3, "A").Value = ...
Cells(4, "A").Value = ...
```

Instead of the being the current worksheet in the current workbook, I want to create and load it into a csv file, to a give path

Say `C:\USERS\Documents\Sample.csv`.

I've seen stuff like

```
     ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"c:\MyFile.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV _
, CreateBackup:=False
```

But this will just save the current workbook to another location, but I don't want to generate data in the current worksheet and then save, rather I want to export right away? Is there anyway I can do that. Maybe making like `ActiveWorkbook = //pathname` and then Activating it ?

Comment: First open a new workbook.  Then have your macro deposit data in the new workbook.  Then have you macro save the new workbook as csv in your folder of choice with your name of choise.  Then close the new workbook.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent  I'm using `Workbooks.Add` to create another workbook. How would I activate now to make sure im importing to it ... is something like `NewWorkbook.Sheets(1).Activate` ?

Comment: Don't use just workbooks.add... use something like... dim wb as workbook // Set wb = workbooks.add // with wb ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can write to a CSV quite simply using VBA.
An example could be:

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

Dim My_filenumber As Integer
Dim logSTR As String

My_filenumber = FreeFile

logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(2, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(3, "A").Value & " , "
logSTR = logSTR & Cells(4, "A").Value

Open "C:\USERS\Documents\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
    Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution does not handle cases where whitespace or newlines or commas exist in your data.  Always use a real CSV function rather than concatenating your own strings.

Comment: dataless... rather than hinting at a better solution and not really adding to the site... please, take the time to post your better solution. I am always happy to learn. Maybe, try not to knock others down, rather try to help them up.

Answer (score 9):

Use the .move to make a new book of the target sheet, then .saveas the newly created book as a CSV. Adjust the Pathname to adjust the directory where you want your csv saved.

```
    Pathname = "" & Thisworkbook.path & "YourName.csv"
    Sheets("Sheet you want as CSV").Move
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
```

Comment: You missing backslash at the path in front of the filename otherwise it will save at wrong place. I still consider this is the best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just modified the code by @CharlieSmith to a fairly simple and more usable code, which will convert all the sheets in your workbook to new csv files named with respective sheet names.

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()
Dim i As Integer
Dim WS_Count As Integer

WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To WS_Count
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
     PathName = "" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ws.Name & ".csv"
    ws.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=PathName, _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
Next i

End Sub
```

Hope this helps